# How to get the time from power on system to showing user login view in Linux?

Tags: linux

I want to get the time from power on system to showing user login view in Linux, how to do?
Can it work only with shell?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at bootchart: http://www.bootchart.org/index.html
Several Windows/Linux power on to desktop speed trails mention this as a neat way of finding out what your linux system is doing. Also see /proc/stat:

```
perl -ne 'print scalar localtime $1 if /^btime (\d+)/' /proc/stat
```

Answer (score 0):

- Get a stopwatch.
- Start it when you press the power on button.
- Stop it when you see the login screen.
- Make a note of the time.

Seriously though, why not put a question like this into Google? There's loads of relevant links, like this one: http://elinux.org/Boot_Time

Boot Chart seems to be popular too: http://www.bootchart.org/